# Logging file names in cosmos db using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have one scenario to implement: I am reading files in ADLS using ADF and copying into another location. While doing that, I need to capture file names and store in cosmos db. Does anybody has done such scenario, please suggest. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get Metadata` activity get file metadata such as file name. Using this pattern, you can then push this value to the db collection in cosmos database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get Metadata activity to get file names. Then create Azure Function activity and pass your file names to it. Finally, you need generate `id` property and insert into Cosmos DB container.